# I'm getting random "Plan executor error during find command" errors

Tags: query-performance, mongodb

My max time for queries is 2secs (2000ms).

However when I try to manually query the script, there is nothing wrong with the query as it finishes executing after 0.002 secs.

I've checked my server resources that timeframe but its usage seems normal.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-13T13:33:07.794+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",
 "id":23798,   
"ctx":"conn89722",
"msg":"Plan executor error during find command",
"attr":{"error":{"code":50,"codeName":"MaxTimeMSExpired","errmsg":"operation exceeded time limit"},
"stats":{"stage":"PROJECTION_SIMPLE","nReturned":1,"works":1,"advanced":1,"needTime":0,"needYield":0,
"saveState":1,"restoreState":0,"isEOF":1,"transformBy":{},
"inputStage":{"stage":"IDHACK","nReturned":1,"works":1,"advanced":1,"needTime":0,"needYield":0,
"saveState":1,"restoreState":0,"isEOF":1,"keysExamined":1,"docsExamined":1}},
"cmd":{"find":"UserToken",
"filter":{"_id":"666280-1663057397-rYi3XASSvzvzJdy8txMgQbw"},"projection":{"UserId":1,"_id":1,"DeviceId":1,"RequestComingFromType":1,"DeviceName":1,"IpAddress":1,
"CountryCode":1,"ExpiredDate":1,"DefaultExchange":1},"limit":1,
"maxTimeMS":2000,"$db":"db1","lsid":{"id":{
"$uuid":"5zc4-4283-23e5-bggb-cdrw24a5c77"}},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1663047184,"i":11}},
"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"aBYlU3UfyBSI+zIb/3M5o/3Ndug=","subType":"0"}},
"keyId":7096455441047093252}}}}}
```

Is there anything to look out for based on this log?